# create user define tag in smarty and how to get the content within it

Tags: php, tags, smarty

in smarty `Smarty_Compiler.class.php` performed some operation between two tags like `{if}{/if}`
if i want to get text within the new tag  then how to proceedi tried inside

```
function _compile_tag($template_tag)
    {
     ....
     switch ($tag_command) {
    -----
     case 'newtag':
      break;
     case  '/newtag':
       break;
      }
```

How can i get the content of tpl within the new tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should create a Smarty plugin.** You can read documentations **[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl)** (about extending Smarty) and **[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl)** (more specific, about create **block functions plugins**).

Basically, you have to create your `smarty_make_pdf()` PHP function (see parameters in the second link I gave you), place it in a file called `block.make_pdf.php` (see **[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.naming.conventions.tpl)**) and tell Smarty to search for plugins in the folder you created that file using `$smarty->addPluginsDir()` (see **[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.plugins.dir.tpl)**).

*PS: I'm supposing you are using Smarty 3.*

Answer (score 4):

***You really shouldn't*** be editing the core Smarty code to achieve this.

Look into **registerPlugin()** if you're using Smarty 3 (or **register_block()** if you're on Smarty 2).

These methods will allow you to create your own Smarty tags and write handler functions that implement them.

Comment: Actually I want to make new tag for pdf

Comment: Actually i want to make new tag for pdf like {make_pdf}{/make_pdf}

Comment: Yes, the above should be perfectly suitable for that (though it seems like an odd way to do it!). Perhaps you can tell us a little more about the problem you're trying to solve?